# Installing cp210x driver for GPS receiver

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, gps

I'm trying in vain to mount a Transystem G-Log 760 GPS logger on a system running Xubuntu 16.04.

According to the manual of GPSBabel this device should be accessible via something like :

```
gpsbabel -t -w -i mtk,erase -f /dev/ttyUSB0 -o gpx -F out.gpx
```

But it doesn't work because **the 'ttyUSB0' device does not exist.**

**What do I have to do in order to make it appear ?**

The device was shipped with a link to the source code for the cp210x driver, and the following instructions:

```
Ubuntu:
1. make ( your cp210x driver )
2. cp cp210x.ko to /lib/modules/<kernel-version>/kernel/drivers/usb/serial
3. insmod /lib/modules/<kernel-version/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
4. insmod cp210x.ko
```

I did not know my exact kernel version, but I nevertheless typed 'make' in the directory containing the source and received among others the following message:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic'
```

So I checked the directory '/lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/drivers/usb/serial' assuming that this is the kernel version needed and discovered that a **file 'cp210x.ko' exists already**.

**I therefore executed only the 2 'insmod' instructions**, without getting any message in return.

**DMESG** contains the following lines:

```
[ 9260.793858] usb 3-3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=3329
[ 9260.793867] usb 3-3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=0
[ 9260.793872] usb 3-3.3: Product: GPS Receiver
[ 9260.793877] usb 3-3.3: Manufacturer: MTK
```

**LSUSB -v**:

```
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0e8d:3329 MediaTek Inc. Qstarz BT-Q1000XT
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            2 Communications
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0e8d MediaTek Inc.
  idProduct          0x3329 Qstarz BT-Q1000XT
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           3 MTK
  iProduct                4 GPS Receiver
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           67
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              1 GPS COM(data_if)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                28
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              2 GPS COM(comm_if)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: I came across this question when I had a similar issue; if this is still a problem for you, you might want to take a look at [the solution I found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935350/ubuntu-16-04-1-usbserial-missing/984031#984031).