# Ubuntu 16.04.1 usbserial missing

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel

What is the deal with usbserial kernel module in current Ubuntu version? I cannot install any drivers, which depend on usbserial.ko.
How I got to this: 
When I connect CP2102 Virtual COM Port (VCP) adapter to USB I get this output:

```
[ 1893.942663] usb 1-1.1.4.2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[ 1894.052823] usb 1-1.1.4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60
[ 1894.052826] usb 1-1.1.4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1894.052828] usb 1-1.1.4.2: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[ 1894.052829] usb 1-1.1.4.2: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[ 1894.052831] usb 1-1.1.4.2: SerialNumber: 0001
[ 1895.067552] cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_generic_open (err 0)
[ 1895.067565] cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_generic_close (err 0)
[ 1895.067579] cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_deregister_drivers (err 0)
[ 1895.067595] cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_register_drivers (err 0)
```

`$ lsmod | grep 210x` and `$ lsmod | grep usbserial` outputs nothing

Then I tried to rebuild the driver. Downloaded new CP210x driver form http://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers

```
$ make
$ cp ./cp210x.ko /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko
$ insmod /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Also `$ modinfo usbserial` outputs

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'usbserial': No such file or directory
```

My system info: `4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

What is going on here and how to fix it? And how to get drivers up and running?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem you mention with my SiLabs CP2102-based ESP32-DevKitC board from Espressif. You don't mention the environment you're using, but I was running Ubuntu as a VirtualBox VM, which turned out to be the source of my problem.

The problem is that **USB Serial drivers aren't installed by default** in Ubuntu images designed for VM and cloud use.

To resolve the issue, install the `linux-image-extra-virtual` package by running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
```

Once I installed that package, I got a `/dev/ttyUSB0` serial device shortly after connecting my USB device to my (host) Mac.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. You just need to install `linux-modules-extra` which contains the driver for your kernel.

With the following command:

`sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`