# Problem with building kernel for Ubuntu 18.04 on VM

Tags: usb, kernel, compiling

I am trying to build kernel on VM. The kernel fails with these errors:

> AS      arch/x86/boot/header.o
>     CC      arch/x86/boot/version.o
>     LD      arch/x86/boot/setup.elf
>     OBJCOPY arch/x86/boot/setup.bin
>     OBJCOPY arch/x86/boot/vmlinux.bin
>     BUILD   arch/x86/boot/bzImage
>   Setup is 15580 bytes (padded to 15872 bytes).
>   System is 4761 kB
>   CRC c6afaf7f
>   Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#4)
>   Building modules, stage 2.
>   MODPOST 856 modules
>   ERROR:"put_tty_driver" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_unregister_driver"[ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_register_driver" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_set_operations" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_std_termios" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "__tty_alloc_driver" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_port_register_device" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_port_init" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_termios_baud_rate" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_port_open" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_insert_flip_string_fixed_flag" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko]undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_flip_buffer_push" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "__tty_insert_flip_char" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_standard_install" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_port_close" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_port_hangup" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_port_tty_wakeup" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_port_put" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_unregister_device" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_vhangup" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_port_tty_get" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   ERROR: "tty_port_tty_hangup" [ubuntu/xr-usb-serial/xr_usb_serial_common.ko] undefined!
>   scripts/Makefile.modpost:92: recipe for target'__modpost' failed
>   make[1]: *** [__modpost] Error 1
>
>   Makefile:1286: recipe for target 'modules' failed
>
>   make: *** [modules] Error 2

I found sombody having problem with USB drivers on this post [Ubuntu 16.04.1 usbserial missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935350/ubuntu-16-04-1-usbserial-missing) . But this doesnt help.
I have downloaded neceaserry files for building the kernel from:
git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/bionic
, so there shouldnt be anything missing

Comment: It looks like you did something wrong when setting up the build environment but it's hard to guess from the error output alone. What exactly did you do? Which instructions did you follow?

Comment: Hi, well I am folowing:   <https://www.embedded.com/getting-started-with-embedded-linux-part-five/>, togeather with <https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel>.  I did remove some drivers in .config file (with make menufonfig), not sure if this could be caused by those changes

Comment: No, removing a driver in `make menuconfig` shouldn't cause those errors. For one thing, `make menuconfig` manages dependencies and won't let you deselect a feature that is needed by some other feature you selected. What do you mean by "following together"? Those two recipes are quite different approaches, one using the `fakeroot debian/rules` command and the other, the standard kernel `make` mechanism. Mixing the two may well lead to problems.

Comment: The first one (https://www.embedded.com/getting-started-with-embedded-linux-part-five/) mentions:  "Each of the major distributions describes how they build a kernel. For Fedora, the description is on the Fedora Wiki and for Ubuntu it is available on the community site. Each of these will install the source used to build your VM system."

Comment: I'm not sure the "BuildYourOwnKernel" page is what the author of "Getting started with Embedded Linux" had in mind when he wrote that. Okay, so what were the actual commands you used?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I did use fakeroot as well as make. The problem was that when I would just use make, the build would fail on purgatory.o, and no similar fail is mentioned on forums so I started going through the ubuntu community site, and after fakeroot and some other instalations, the build did no longer fail on purgatory.o

Comment: If you belive this may be the problem, I will try again and just use make command, and see where this gets me

Comment: Hi, I tried building the kernel using only the instructions from first link. There was a problem with building purgatory.o because copying file from another directory wasnt successful, I fixed that manually, and finally got the same problem as explained above. Then I started digging and saw that the file that was actually missing (xr_usb_serial_common.ko) wasnt build, and that there is a similar file (xr_usb_serial_common.o). So the real question is how do I get .ko file from .o file

Comment: The step that's emitting the error messages is the step to build xr_usb_serial_common.ko from xr_usb_serial_common.o. So the real question is, why is that step not finding those symbols, which are actually standard symbols of the kernel tty subsystem. That's why I wrote your build environment seems somehow borked.

Answer (score 0):

so the problem was my mistake (or my wrong presumption), I presumed that I can edit .config file with "make menuconfig" without worrying what should I include in compile, and what I could leave out. The idea in my head was that GUI would warn me if something must be included in the compile, because some features couldnt be NOT included in compile. The problem in the end was that I didnt include some features in the compile, so the xr_usb_serial_common.ko couldnt be generated. I found the solution by going through top answers of these two https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476990/difference-between-o-and-ko-file  , and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812418/kernel-driver-external-modules-not-building-completely  . Hope it helps somebody